# How can I get the absolute image path in react-native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I need to create a video based on audio and an image. I saved an image in my app folder `/src/img/test.jpg`. To create a video, I need an absolute image path.

I tried `react-native-fs`. Here is some code, where I'm trying to copy an image from src path to DocumentDirectoryPath.

```
const dest = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/test.jpg`;
const path =  'src/img/test.jpg'

RNFS.copyFile(path, dest)
  .then(() => FileViewer.open(dest))
    .then(() => {
      RNFS.readDir(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath) 
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('GOT RESULT', result);
      })
    })
  .catch(_err => {
    console.log(_err);
});
```

And I'm getting the error: 
`Error: The file “test.jpg” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.`

Comment: for static images you will need to use 'require' .  in the code you pasted the image is not embedded in the app. See example here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't access

```
const path =  'src/img/test.jpg'
```

in run time because it's bundled within your app

try this :

```
const dest = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/test.jpg`;
const img =  require('src/img/test.jpg');

RNFS.writeFile(dest, img, "base64")
  .then(() => FileViewer.open(dest))
  .then(() => {
     RNFS.readDir(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath) 
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('GOT RESULT', result);
     })
  })
  .catch(_err => {
     console.log(_err);
  });
```

Comment: Glad to help you